# Featured meta posts use main site icon in iOS app feed

Tags: bug, ios-app

The "Featured meta post" feed items use the icon from the main site, even though they feature questions from the meta site.

I could possibly see an argument for this being intentional if the trigger used to show these questions was that they appeared in the Community Bulletin on the main site, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Given that, it seems to me that they should be using the icon from the meta site instead.

Example:

[image: meta site questions with main site icon]